# Sendgrid mail new c# client broken?

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I understand this breaking change:

> Use new SendGridMessage() instead of SendGrid.GetInstance()

However, when doing the following:

```
var transportWeb = Web.GetInstance(credentials);
```

I am told that GetInstance doesn't exist?

What's going on? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, missed this one in the updated docs. You also need to use the constructor for the `Web` type instead of the old factory method.

```
// Create an Web transport for sending email.
var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);
```

The [readme](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/README.md) is now fixed as well. Thanks.